# Outlook for Mac O365 Exchange Online protocol used

Tags: outlook, mac

I’m struggling to find an answer to a probably simple question but since I’m not an Exchange Admin maybe I’m looking for wrong information. What is the protocol used by Outlook for Mac to send emails through O365 Exchange Online (I assume that all the corp mail is going via it anyway).

I was able to find this from [About O365 Email Protocol Challenges](https://origin-symwisedownload.symantec.com/resources/webguides/sgos/o365/concepts/about_mailprotocols_co.htm)

> Outlook Mac for Apple clients uses Exchange Web Services (EWS). SOAP
> provides the messaging framework for messages sent between the client
> application and the Exchange server. The SOAP messages are sent by
> HTTP.

The MS articel https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-outlook-for-mac-with-outlook-for-windows-bd54cb79-d367-4c2f-89c7-3e5d16618f87 states:

[Outlook 2016 for Mac Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVF1G.png)

Could someone please correct or confirm ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

“Outlook Mac for Apple clients uses Exchange Web Services (EWS). SOAP provides the messaging framework for messages sent between the client application and the Exchange server. The SOAP messages are sent by HTTP.” I think this is correct.
We also could refer to the following thread: Outlook for Mac 2011 - http error when sending mailhttps://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/outlook-for-mac-2011-http-error-when-sending-mail/efc6579d-af99-4a01-8deb-2e4f7e4debe3?auth=1 it sent soap message via HTTP.